# Error: Could not find or load main class on Eclipse Mac

Tags: selenium-webdriver

everything i try to run program, i get Error: Could not find or load main class error message,i try to explore every possible medium but nothing work..

please help me out over this, m not able to proceed with my selenium code on Eclipse mac[Getting Error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apFVd.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  See here on how to craft a question that is likely to be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to move all your files into the default package. After that save them and it should run.